# Minimum Height Div Alignment

Tags: html, css

I got this code online and it satisfies my need of having a min-height div. But I also want the content to be vertically center aligned. Can someone please help?  I have gone through many options given in these forums but they do not work in combination with this particuar css. And this particular css I must use to get a min-height div.

```
<html><style type="text/css">
  .prop {
    float:right;
    width:1px;

  }

  #footer {
    clear:both;
    border-top:2px solid #000000;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:80%;
  }

  .min200px {
    height:200px;
  }
  </style>
</html>
<body>

<div>
  <div class="prop min200px"></div>

I want this content to be vertically center aligned

  <div id="footer">
    Copyight 2012 - xyz
  </div>
</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not wrapping the text in any element. It would be tough to do then.

Keep the text in a child element and give `display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;`  to it and also `line-height` to the parent element with a value equal to the element's height. And later as the `line-height` value inherits to child elements, give `line-height` to the child element as well to make it look nice.

**Changed HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="prop min200px">
        <div>I want this content to be vertically center aligned</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Copyight 2012 - xyz</div>
</div>
```

---

**Changed CSS**:

```
.prop{
    line-height:200px;
}
.prop>div{
    line-height:20px; /* or  1em */
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/426Lm/5/)**

FYI, you mentioned that you are using `min-height` property. but you haven't used it anywhere in the code. (you just declared a class name of that property name).

Answer (score 0):

I would use javascript/jQuery for this. This is just to point you out in the right direction

```
<div id="center">
  <div class="prop min200px"></div>
  I want this content to be vertically center aligned
  <div id="footer">
      Copyight 2012 - xyz
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var wh= window.height,
        h= $('#center').height(),
        x = (wh-h)/2;
    $('#center').css({"marginTop":"x"})
</script>
```

what this does: it checks your window heigh and your div height. it subtracts from each other. After that this value is divided by 2 (for equal space between top and bottom)
The margin-top is changed by this so you would have the equal space. This doesnt make the div Center fixed position (if you scroll it still changes) so if you want to change that you need to make some CSS adjustments to make it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
```

I 
want 
this
 content
 to
 be 
vertically 
center 
aligned

Copyight 2012 - xyz

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved. Thank you all. But I needed a minimum height no matter what the content was and so I used above css code. But in addition to that I wanted my content to be centered. So I use the below code. The extra css is for my other needs:

```
@font-face { font-family: MyCustomFont;  src: url("file:///fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf") }body,html,table { font-family: MyCustomFont; font-size:14.0pt;} body,html {text-align: center;vertical-align:middle;line-height: normal; margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;}html {display: table;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;}body {vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;}.minHeight { float:right; width:1px; height:94px; }

<div class="minHeight"></div><table height=94px align=center><tr>
<td align=center>My centered text </td></tr></table>
```